# HAML + AngularJS: Create custom "ng" prefix like "data"

Tags: angularjs, haml

HAML understands a basic hash for the "data" keyword, so that:

`%div{ data: { id: "5", name: "carsten" } }`

is equivalent to

`%div{ 'data-id' => "5", 'data-name' => "carsten" }`

IMHO the former syntax is much more readable.

AngularJS uses a lot of ng-something attributes. Is it possible to configure HAML, so that:

`%html{ 'ng-app' => "myApp", 'ng-controller' => "myCtrl" }`

can be written as

`%html{ ng: { app: "myApp", controller: "myCtrl" } }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t need to configure anything, this is how the current version works already:

```haml
%html{ ng: { app: "myApp", controller: "myCtrl" } }
```

produces:

```html
<html ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'></html>
```

The docs need updating, but the [current behaviour](https://github.com/haml/haml/commit/5deaf29e4919e73a15aed5ab04b017f624edaf48) is *any* attribute with a value that is a hash is expanded in this way, not just `data`.